# Using PDFCreator to convert docx to pdf in a VB .NET function but it's not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a VB .NET function and I need to convert a .docx document to .pdf using that function. What I'm doing is I'm using PDFCreator from commandline with a batch created and executed inside my VB .NET function, but somehow it's not working and I have no idea what is it that I'm doing wrong.
Any suggestions?
Forgot to say that I need this process to be completely hidden from user interacting with the application, so the conversion to .pdf must be automatic, without user interaction. The user only needs to click "Convert" and the function should do the rest.

```
Public dirTemp As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp
----
Function GeneratePDF_W10(ByVal PathWord As String, PathPDF As String)
    Try
        Dim pathScriptPDF As String = dirTemp & "\PDFScriptW10.bat"
        Dim write As New System.IO.StreamWriter(pathScriptPDF, False)

        write.WriteLine("C:\Program Files\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe /InitializeSettings")
        write.WriteLine("C:\Program Files\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe /PrintFile=""" & PathWord & """ /OutputFile=""" & PathPDF & """")

        write.Close()


        Process.Start(pathScriptPDF)

        Dim count As Integer = 0

        Do While Exists(PathPDF) = False
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            count = count + 1
            If count >= 60 Then Exit Do
        Loop

        If Exists(PathPDF) = True Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return 0

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Return 0
    End Try


End Function
```

Comment: If you can use Office Interop, you can convert .docx files into .pdf without external library, with **ExportAsFixedFormat** and **WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF** flag.

Comment: Using Office Interop actually works so thanks for that. Actually I have another problem now. The document I'm trying to convert has some .wmf images anchored to it. When I convert the file with Office Interop, there seems to be a scale problem with the images which appear way larger than they actually are, and only the top-left corner is displayed. Any idea why?